# Handle assets with Webpack and React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, webpack, babeljs, metro-bundler

I'm transpiling my React Native TypeScript app with Webpack before giving it to Metro, for multiple reasons. The main one being the [lack of support](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9838) for parameter decorators in Babel.

Everything worked well until I started using the [Image](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image) component.

When I add an image in a component, I get the following error :

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`, expected one of type [number].
```

In my `webpack.config.js`, I'm handling the assets with the following config :

```
{
    generator: {
        filename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]',
    },
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
},
```

My guess is that Metro does something more when processing the assets. How can I replicate this behavior via Webpack ? I couldn't find any loader for this.